# Can I detect if an image goes under my logo?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On my homepage I have these two elements:

[image]

Both elements are SVG images. If the user minimizes the homepage now, I have on some devices the problem that the logo (which has the same color like by background) goes over the background and is invisible now until my mobile layout get's enabled.

I have this problem in some screen solutions and it's not very easy to change the background for each resolution (instead of the default ones like mobile, tabled etc.).

So I want to know if it's possible to detect if my logo goes over the background image. If it begins to go over it, I want to make the overflowing part in a white color and keep the other part blue so that it's still visible:

[image]

If this can work, I will provide a simple code which fits my situation because when it's possible, I don't think that I can't get it working by my own because of the complexity.

**Update**
Because DCR told me that it's possible, I'm providing now an example:

```css
#content {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg width='580' height='400' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3cg%3e%3ctitle%3ebackground%3c/title%3e%3crect fill='%23fff' id='canvas_background' height='402' width='582' y='-1' x='-1'/%3e%3cg display='none' overflow='visible' y='0' x='0' height='100%25' width='100%25' id='canvasGrid'%3e%3crect fill='url(%23gridpattern)' stroke-width='0' y='0' x='0' height='100%25' width='100%25'/%3e%3c/g%3e%3c/g%3e%3cg%3e%3ctitle%3eLayer 1%3c/title%3e%3crect stroke='%23000' id='svg_1' height='432.000047' width='409.999983' y='-12.546892' x='211.500021' stroke-width='0' fill='%2330a8a8'/%3e%3c/g%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  background-position: top right;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

#logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <img id="logo" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='389' height='175' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctitle%3Ebackground%3C/title%3E%3Crect fill='none' id='canvas_background' height='177' width='391' y='-1' x='-1'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctitle%3ELayer 1%3C/title%3E%3Crect id='svg_2' height='1' width='2' y='71.5' x='-455.5' stroke-opacity='null' stroke-width='0' stroke='%23000' fill='%2330a8a8'/%3E%3Ctext font-weight='bold' xml:space='preserve' text-anchor='start' font-family='Arvo, sans-serif' font-size='52' id='svg_3' y='105.5' x='12.476563' stroke-opacity='null' stroke-width='0' stroke='%23000' fill='%2330a8a8'%3ECookiefreunde%3C/text%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E">
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell me the reason of your downvote so that I can improve my question! Thanks :)

Comment: Not my downvote but you probably got it because of no code and/or being probably too broad/unclear. Most of today's frameworks take into account overlapping elements. Bootstrap is one of them that usually does a good job.

Comment: while I didn't down vote you, show your code!

Comment: If you really want you could do some calculation with the elements offset and width/height. However as others pointed out, there might be better solution available if you can explain your problem in more detail.You should be able to style your elements so they can't overlap.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks for the hint. But as I already described I'll add some code if this is even possible. And I want to build an own solution instead of installing a huge framework for just one job.

Comment: @DCR Is this even possible? If yes, you'll get a lot of code.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Sure thing. Yet, bootstrap isn't a framework though, sorry... I used the wrong term; there isn't much to install really, just a few scripts/css. If you haven't tried or considered it, it might prove to be helpful.

Comment: yes, it is possible. You can do this in javascript.

Comment: Can't you go around it with CSS media queries?

Comment: @AnisR. It's not that easy in a responsive layout. I've already tried a lot of solutions the last 3 months but there are still some problems so I came up with the idea described above.

Comment: @DCR Ok. You'll get your code. I'll code an example.

Comment: @DCR I've added an example that fits my situation. I have refrained from rebuilding my whole homepage. You can resize the div so that the logo overflows my background. In this case you'll see the problem.

Comment: Instead of worrying about the logo and image intersection, use [CSS media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to _guarantee_ they can't overlap. by repositioning things when the viewport gets too narrow (or even delegate most of that work to something like bootstrap, because why reinvent the wheel when all you need is a custom tyre)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Please trust me. It' can't work in my case.... I know about the media queries but I've special cases that don't work. My example is just a coding example which shows not the exact problem but you can trust me it's there. I'm working with a copyright illustration and I'm not allowed to share it here. I've tried a lot with media queries, asked other colleges and tried a lot. You can trust me. This is the only idea I had left and DCR told me it's possible to change the color on overflow (for backup if no querie fits)

Comment: I couldn't care less about trust, I just care about whether your post describes your actual problem. It sounds like it doesn't, so: update you post to _actually_ describe the real problem. Reduce it, generecise it, all fine, but do not write up something that is _different_ from your actual problem.

Comment: You can use `mix-blend-mode` to keep the text visible: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4ycj7wn8/

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right this will do the job for you, by decrease/increase css for .banner left: - you can test it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// add + logo width + 1px , width 30 + 1 = 31px
var logo = $('.logo').offset().left + 51;
var banner = $('.banner').offset().left;


if(logo > banner){
console.log('banner is over the logo')
}

console.log('logo:' +logo)
console.log('banner:'+ banner)
})
```

```css
.logo{
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
}

.banner{
 height: 130px;
 width: 130px;
 position: relative;
 left: -5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="logo" src="https://cdn-a.william-reed.com/var/wrbm_gb_food_pharma/storage/images/publications/cosmetics/cosmeticsdesign-asia.com/headlines/regulation-safety/why-iso-standards-are-crucial-for-organic-and-natural-transparency-cftas-president/10238025-1-eng-GB/Why-ISO-standards-are-crucial-for-organic-and-natural-transparency-CFTAS-president_wrbm_large.jpg">


<img class="banner" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
```

Comment: And how sould this help how? As I asked in my question: I want to change the SVG color part that is over my background and keep the other part in the original color.

Comment: bu topic title "Can I detect if an image goes under my logo?" and this "So I want to know if it's possible to detect if my logo goes over the background image. " i create my answer , sorry i didnt understand you correct, you can ignore my answer than